# Replace boot drive with ZFS pool?

Tags: zfs

If I have already installed a system that has 3 spare 1TB disks in it, can I create a zfs pool on it and transfer the system to it then boot off it ? Once thats done I could then add the existing disk back to the ZFS pool ?

Is this possible ?

Comment: Is your boot manager capable of mounting a ZFS pool? I'm not aware of one.

Comment: I see there is this https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/grub ?